# Car Park Database Design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

We have two number plate reader cameras on the entrance and exit of the car park that will generate a CSV file when a detection takes place, which then gets automatically loaded into the database, as well as a barrier on the entrance operated automatically by the camera's "whitelist", which in turn is generated and controlled from within the database and exported into a text file.

Initially, I thought this would be a simple 3-table database as per the design below, but i am quickly realising that this is not the case:

My initial designs:

```
tbl_in :      ID (autonum/PK), Plate, Date_in, Time_in    
tbl_out:      ID (Autonum/PK), Plate, Date_out, Time_out    
tblwhitelist: Plate(PK), Country Code, Description
```

Currently,the only relationship I can think of would be:

**Whitelist plate-Plate_in &  plate_out**  where one plate in the whitelist could be seen many times within the in & out tables

---

This has then been made more complicated by (and this is where my brain is really melting!) the queries that have been specified (brackets show columns and basic logic am thinking of for results):

1. **"Whitelisted Vehicles on site today"** (IF plate is on Whitelist:  Plate, Description, Time_in,Time_out [if plate seen on OUT table today,otherwise null])
2. **"non-Whitelisted vehicles seen today"** (IF plate is NOT on Whitelist: Plate, Time_in,Time_out [if plate seen on OUT table, otherwise null])
3. **"Whitelisted Vehicles time on site for today/last 7 days/last 30 days/last 90 days** (IF plate on Whitelist: Plate, Description, Date_in, Time_in, Date_out, Time_out) this would have duplicate entries of same plates for multiple times on site
4. **"Non-Whitelisted vehicles time on site for today/last 7 days/last 30 days/last 90 days** (IF plate not on whitelist: Plate, Date_in, Time_in, Date_out, Time_out) This Would have duplicate entries of same plates for multiple times on site

What i really need help with is some ideas on how to sort out the Query code to get these working properly. This is one of the last main hurdles for me in this project. unfortunately, it's a hurdle the size of Everest. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I cannot see any reason to separate ins and outs. I'd just have a table like this: events(plate*,datetime*,event(either in or out)) where * = component of PK. I think this might simplify things slightly when you come on to the next part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Straweberry's post, you don't need two tables for `in` and `out`. You could have one for that like:

```
 tblVehicleEvent : ID (autonum/PK), Plate, EventDate, EventTime, EventType
```

where EventType has either values of **IN** or **OUT**.

Or you could have merge TimeIn and TimeOut and DateIn and DateOut like:

```
 tblVehicleEvent : ID (autonum/PK), Plate, DateIn, DateOut, TimeIn, TimeOut
```

I think the second one would be easier for your query later on based on your requirements.

The Queries would be like below:

1. Whitelisted Vehicles on site today" (IF plate is on Whitelist:
   Plate, Description, Time_in,Time_out [if plate seen on OUT table
   today,otherwise null])

   *SELECT W.Plate, Description, TimeIn, TimeOut FROM tblVehcileEvent V 

     INNER JOIN tblWhitelist W 

     ON V.Plate = W.Plate 

     WHERE DateIn = curdate()*
2. "non-Whitelisted vehicles seen today" (IF plate is NOT on Whitelist:
   Plate, Time_in,Time_out [if plate seen on OUT table, otherwise
   null])

   *SELECT Plate, TimeIn, TimeOut 

    FROM tblVehicleEvent 

    WHERE Plate NOT IN (SELECT Plate FROM tblWhitelist)*
3. "Whitelisted Vehicles time on site for today/last 7 days/last 30
   days/last 90 days (IF plate on Whitelist: Plate, Description,
   Date_in, Time_in, Date_out, Time_out) this would have duplicate
   entries of same plates for multiple times on site

   *SELECT W.Plate, Description, TimeIn, TimeOut 

     FROM tblVehcileEvent V 

     INNER JOIN tblWhitelist W 

     ON V.Plate = W.Plate 

     WHERE DateIn BETWEEN startDate and EndDate*
4. "Non-Whitelisted vehicles time on site for today/last 7 days/last 30
   days/last 90 days (IF plate not on whitelist: Plate, Date_in,
   Time_in, Date_out, Time_out) This Would have duplicate entries of
   same plates for multiple times on site

   *SELECT Plate, TimeIn, TimeOut 

     FROM tblVehicleEvent 

     WHERE Plate NOT IN (SELECT Plate FROM tblWhitelist) 

     AND DateIn BETWEEN startDate and EndDate*

Comment: If using the latter option, then you'll need to look at INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: I can see how this would work, but how would this affect the queries that i need to produce?

Comment: Check my queries @almg.

Answer (score 0):

Like Strawberry suggested, use a single table where each record tracks the complete stay of a vehicle in the park.

```
tbl_stay

ID (autonum/PK), Plate, Date_in, Time_in, Date_out, Time_out
```

If you use two different tables you'll have to do complicated queries to correlate the data. What tells you that one line in `tbl_in` is related to that other line in `tbl_out` ? You'd have to compare the plate numbers and find the Date_out / Time_out closest to the Date_in / Time_in...

So just use a single table, but DON'T use Edper's first suggestion, you'd end up with the same problem, this time filtering the table based on the event type and trying to correlate one row with another.

I think your first query would look something like that :

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_whitelisted
INNER JOIN tbl_stay
ON tbl_whitelisted.Plate = tbl_stay.Plate
WHERE tbl_stay.Date_in <= curdate()
AND (tbl_stay.Date_out IS NULL OR tbl_stay.Date_out = curdate())
```

The second one would then be :

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_stay
WHERE tbl_stay.Date_in <= curdate()
AND (tbl_stay.Date_out IS NULL OR tbl_stay.Date_out = curdate())
AND tbl_stay.Plate NOT IN (SELECT Plate FROM tbl_whitelist)
```

Or maybe this (what does "seen" today mean ? I guess it means the vehicle's plate has been scanned at least once today, so the preceding version would not do since it also returns vehicles that are still on site today, but that came in yesterday...)

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_stay
WHERE (tbl_stay.Date_in = curdate() OR tbl_stay.Date_out = curdate())
AND tbl_stay.Plate NOT IN (SELECT Plate FROM tbl_whitelist)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will give this a go. "Seen today" does refer to plate detections from the camera. How would this method be affected by duplicate plates (eg: vehicle leaves site then returns later)?

Comment: You'd have multiple rows then. If you want a single row for each car, just use SELECT DISTINCT Plate for instance

Comment: I'm working my way through this solution and i've come across another conundrum: inserting data into the tbl_stay. In addition to the main tables i mentioned in the question, i also have 2 buffer tables ONLY used to import the CSV data, then insert it into the primary tables with an auto ID primary key. inserting the Plate, Date_in and Time_in works fine, but the Date_out and Time out are getting dumped into new rows. I am assuming the insert for the "out" data would have to have some condition looking at the plate and/or the contents of the "out" fields in the table?

Comment: The only way the data for `Date_out` and `Time_out` should end up in `tbl_stay` is through an UPDATE query. You want to retrieve the most recent row for the current license plate, and change it. For example `UPDATE tbl_stay SET Date_out = <today>, Time_out = <now> WHERE Plate = <current_plate> ORDER BY Date_in DESC, Time_in DESC LIMIT 1`. Or, if you're confident about the integrity of your data, you could update the row where `Date_out` and `Time_out` are NULL (logically there should be only one) : `UPDATE tbl_stay ... WHERE Plate = <current_plate> AND Date_out IS NULL AND Time_out IS NULL`

Comment: You could also "simplify" this by storing all the vehicles that have ever been in the park in a new table, with two columns : `tbl_vehicles (Plate (PK), stay_id)`. When a car comes in, you would INSERT a row in tbl_stay, memorize its PK and then `INSERT INTO tbl_vehicles(Plate, stay_id) VALUES(<current_plate>, <stay_id>) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stay_id = <stay_id>`. So a car you've never seen before gets a new row, while a car that's already in the table gets its stay_id pointed to the current stay. When you need to insert Date_out and Time_out, you just look up the stay_id for that Plate.

Comment: And _then_ you could merge your whitelist into `tbl_vehicles`, by adding a third column of type boolean, simply indicating if the vehicle is whitelisted or not. This could make sense if you have many vehicles whitelisted, but I'd wager if fewer than 70% of the cars are whitelisted, it's better to have a dedicated whitelist table for faster lookups. There are many ways to design for your problem! :)

Comment: thank you for your help. i may give this a whirl. currently i have `insert into hystest.tbl_stay (Plate,Date_in,Time_in) select * from hystest.tblin_buffer` for loading the IN data and `update tbl_stay join tblout_buffer on tblout_buffer.plate=tbl_stay.plate set tbl_stay.date_out=tblout_buffer.Date_out, tbl_stay.time_out=tblout_buffer.time_out` for the OUT data